# Jquery Autocomplete error menuselect and menufocus cannot read property value undefined

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

```
$('.searchName').autocomplete({ 
        source: function(req, res){
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "{{ route('airportSearch') }}", 
                dataType: "json", 
                type: "GET", 
                data: req,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#iconMaps').hide();
                    $('#loadingMaps').show();
                },
                success: function (data){ 
                    $('#iconMaps').show();
                    $('#loadingMaps').hide();
                    res(data);
                    console.log(data)
                }, 
                error: function(err){ 
                    $('#iconMaps').show();
                    $('#loadingMaps').hide();
                } 
            });
        }
    }).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $('<li>')
            .data('ui-autocomplete', item)
            .append('<span><b>' + item.label + '</b></span><br><span>' + item.value + '</span>')
            .appendTo(ul);
    }
```

this my code, i have problem if selected list have error:

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide an example of the resulting `data`.

Comment: This example result data 
[{ cityName: "MADRID"
 label: "MADRID, SPAIN"
 name: "MAD - ADOLFO SUAREZ BARAJAS"
value: "MADRID, SPAIN, (MAD)" }]

Comment: In the `data` example, seems that there are comma's `,` missing between key/value pairs?

Comment: i am sorry. I wrote wrong, should be [{ cityName: "MADRID", label: "MADRID, SPAIN", name: "MAD - ADOLFO SUAREZ BARAJAS", value: "MADRID, SPAIN, (MAD)" }]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after updating JQuery version and fixed it applying few changes in data(), like bellow:

```
.data('uiAutocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $('<li>')
        .data('ui-autocomplete-item', item)
        .append('<span><b>' + item.label + '</b></span><br><span>' + item.value + '</span>')
        .appendTo(ul);
```